# Elementor - put Shortcode around a widget by hook?

Tags: wordpress, hook, action, elementor

does anyone know, how I can put a shortcode around a Elementor Widget.
I need this for that GDPR thing.

[shortcode]
**Elementor Widget**
[/shortcode]

Maybe there is an action hook I can use ... before and after widget.

Thanks for any suggestion,
Denis

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do instead:

1. Go to Elementor Templates > Create New > Select "Section" > Put your widget in it and style it as you want.
2. Copy the template shortcode and keep it with you for eg: [elementor-template id="1234"]
3. In the functions.php you need to add below code:

```
    function shortcode_inception(){
        return do_shortcode('[shortcode]'.do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="1234"]').'[/shortcode]');
    }
    
    add_shortcode('shortcode_inception', 'shortcode_inception');
```

I hope this will help you. Let me know if you face any difficulties here.